# Passing Googlemap latitude and longitude as javascript to HTML form

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

Hi I am currently using GoogleMaps API v3 and I am trying to get the variables for the latitude and longitude and place them in a hidden form as html variables and pass them through a form to a php page. The latitude and longitude are printing out on my page as the span but I cant get them to print in the form.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Untitled 1</title>

   <!-- google maps -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">        </script>

    <!-- jquery -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <!-- jquery UI -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

   <!-- our javascript -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="gmaps.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style4.css" />


   </head>

   <body>

      <input id='gmaps-input-address' type='text'/>

    <div id='gmaps-error'></div>

    <div id='gmaps-canvas'></div>

      <br/>
      <br/>
    Latitude: <span id='gmaps-output-latitude'></span>
      <br/>
      Longitude: <span id='gmaps-output-longitude'></span>
      <br/>     

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function doSomething()
    {
    var lat = document.getElementById('#gmaps-output-latitude');
    lat_element.value = google_maps_api_variable;
    var lon = document.getElementById('#gmaps-output-longitude');
    lon_element.value = google_maps_api_variable;
    document.getElementById("lat").value=lat;
    document.getElementById("lon").value=lon;
    }
    </script>


   <form action="join.php" method="post" onSubmit="doSomething">

   <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="lon" id="lon"/>

   <input type="submit" value="Confirm Address"/>
   </form>
   </body>


   </html>
```

In the Googlemaps API there is a javascript function which holds the latitude and longitude as follows:

```
function update_ui( address, latLng ) {
 $('#gmaps-input-address').autocomplete("close");
 $('#gmaps-input-address').val(address);
 $('#gmaps-output-latitude').html(latLng.lat());
 $('#gmaps-output-longitude').html(latLng.lng());
 }
```

I am very green with Javascript and would really appreciate any help, I have searched other questions to get as far as I am but I am stuck here.

Comment: You don't need an HTML form. You can pass them directly from Javascript to PHP in an AJAX call. HTML is not a programming language, so it is not supposed to hold variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this after the code you already have(to work before the form submits as a click handler of the form submittal buon or something):

```
$('#lat').val($('#gmaps-output-latitude').html());
$('#lon').val($('#gmaps-output-longitude').html());
```

Comment: Cheers for your help John but im still having problems with it.Do you know why the latitude and longitude will print as a <span id="lat"></span>, but not as <input = "text" id= "lat"></input>??Sorry if this is a stupid question this is my first website.Thanks

Comment: @Brian O keeffe input tags dont use tag closers.  the input itself should end with a />.  The jquery being jused there is setting html which is the content inside a tag.  for an input you would set the value using val like I did above.  also, you can only use an id once per page.  I'll admit my code is a bit of a workaround in that it copies the contents of the span tag into the value of the hidden inputs.

Comment: Thanks John, I got the code to work by removing the span and changing the UI_Function to   $('#lat').val(latLng.lat());
  $('#lon').val(latLng.lng()); as you advised.Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

gmaps.js is your js which populates span in your html file. This should be happening through a callback function which i probably think is update_ui. This function might be populating the spans afterwards and your script for populating hidden fields might have already executed. So places the code for populating hidden fields after the callback function call or may be in update_ui itself.

so edit your update_ui function and add

```
$('#lat').val(latLng.lat());
$('#lon').val(latLng.lng());
```

these lines in the function body in end.

Comment: Again thanks a million for the help Sushil, but would you be able to explain why the latitude and longitude will print as a <span id="lat"></span>, but not as <input = "text" id= "lat"></input>??Sorry if this is a stupid question this is my first website.Thanks